# iOS 14 Widgets: Invalidate/Update configuration if e.g. the title of an item changed

Tags: ios, ios14, widgetkit

With my next app update I'll ship new iOS14 widgets. It's a todo list with several lists. So in my widget, the user can pick a list. That list is stored as the ConfigurationIntent.
Is there a way to update the name of such a list, once the user changes it inside the app? I tried with the Apple own reminders app and they also have the same "bug". So I wonder if it's even possible to update the displayName of such an ConfigurationIntent setting.

Comment: See the *Implement an Intent Handler to Provide Dynamic Values* section of [Making a Configurable Widget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget).

Comment: My question was about updating the config... is this possible? I don't see it in the link you shared...